# how to both security web browser request and Restful request in spring security with keycloak

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak

I'm using spring boot security with keycloak to security my app. But I have both normal web browser request (using thymeleaf template), and rest api request (no browser and the method in Controller annotated with @ResponseBody with json format).

From the web guider, I found keycloak will used different client type for browser request (e.g. public client) and for no UI reqeust (bearer-only), and the session in SecurityConfig.java is different, `new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl())` and `new NullAuthenticatedSessionStrategy()`.

So my question is how could I configure the spring security and keycloak for both support browser reqeust and rest api request in one app?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Having a `bearer-only` client makes sense only when you've got another client to authenticate with. In short, these are the three types of client types in Keycloak:

- Public: Permits authentication, without a client secret.
- Confidential: Permits authentication, with a client secret.
- Bearer only: You need to have an access token to access its resources.

Having said that, I don't see the point in making the same application both public and bearer only. As a rule, you make a client per application. So you've got two choices:

- Make your application public or confidential. That will accept browser and non-browser requests. Recommended.
- Divide your application in two and make one who merely serves the UI (public or confidential) and other one which serves the REST API (this will be bearer-only). Still, remember you'll need to log in using the UI client to authenticate yourself. Only advisable if your application API is large enough to be split from the UI.

Comment: Hi @xtreme, how to make the non-browser request for keycloak public client, which http get request header I should set. I only know if using bearer-only client, i can use the "Authetication" header with a valid visit token, but what should I do for the public client type.Thanks!

Comment: For the second solution, yes, it does work. But since my application is just a simple service (with a simple UI for those non-rest users), I don't want to split it if I can.

Comment: As of your first comment, you can use the `Authorization` header for public and confidential clients too.

Comment: I am trying to achieve something similar. I want APIs to be called by another backend (client credentials with client id and client secret, bearer only) and I want to give access to a swagger-ui protected under authentication (without the authorize button). When the user opens the swagger ui it redirects to keycloak for login. Then he can call the APIs from swagger ui using the "try it out" feature since he has the token.